# In Ninject, how can I run custom code on an object after it is created with Bind<..>.ToSelf()?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

In Ninject's dependency injection, if you set up a binding of a class to itself like so:

```
Bind<SomeClass>().ToSelf();
```

Ninject very nicely resolves any dependencies SomeClass has and gives you the object back.  I want to be able to do something to the SomeClass it returns every time it creates a new one, so like a post-processing event.  I could use the .ToMethod (or ToFactoryMethod) binding to explicitly new it up, but I would like all its dependencies resolved by Ninject beforehand.

It wouldu be nice to do something like:

```
Bind<SomeClass>()
    .ToSelf()
    .After(sc => sc.MethodIWantToCall()); // then after here, Ninject returns the object.
```

Is there some way to do this in Ninject 1.0/1.1?

Comment: Is there a problem with performing the task you want to perform in the constructor?

Comment: I suppose there isn't anything wrong with it and that's the practical solution :)  But I thought that, perhaps, for testing or maybe some real scenarios, the MethodIWantToCall() could be considered a part of the object *activation*, which I'm turing over to Ninject, rather than implementation.  But I would agree it's perhaps a minor point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can't put the code you want to execute in the constructor, you can implement `IInitializable` or `IStartable`. The former provides an `Initialize()` method that gets called after all injection has completed, and the latter provides both a `Start()` and `Stop()` method, called during activation and deactivation, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem, but I could not use Nate's solution because I couldn't make the type implement `IInitializable`.  If you're in a similar boat, you can use `.OnActivation` and avoid having to modify the definition of the target types:

```
Bind<SomeClass>().ToSelf().OnActivation(x => ((SomeClass)x).MyInitialize());
```

You can see how we call some arbitrary initialization method (`MyInitialize`) upon activation (instantiation) of the class.

This has the advantage of not baking in a hard dependency to Ninject in your own classes (aside from your modules, of course), thus allowing your types to remain agnostic about the DI-framework you end up using.