# How to get if the object is already retrieved in inject

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject

Is it possible to know that particular dependency already has been satisfied by `ninject` `kernel`? To be clear:

Let's suppose we have this module:

```
Bind<IA>().To<A>();
Bind<IB>().To<B>();
```

And some "client"-code:

```
var a = kernel.Get<IA>();

// how to get here "true" for assumption: "IA was requested (once)"
// and "false" for: "IB was not requested ever"
```

Comment: Why would you ever need that?

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: it is related to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953624/ioc-and-datacontext-disposing-in-asp-net-mvc-2-application. so i need this to know whether i should dispose db (it has been used) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here: [In Ninject, how can I run custom code on an object after it is created with Bind<..>.ToSelf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179148/in-ninject-how-can-i-run-custom-code-on-an-object-after-it-is-created-with-bind/1230969#1230969)

Answer (score 1):

You could use .Before* and .After* in the fluent bindings to hook in a call to something to mark it used. Or you could look at the IDisposable hooks (see the tests in the source download).

There's good background info in http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/ too

Comment: Hmmmm, I haven't find any Before/After hooks in the sources. Can you point more specifically, please?